# If I run electrical current through the conductors in a magnetic shield, can It be used to shield stronger magnetic fields?

Tags: current, electromagnetism, shielding

I'm wondering if running electrical current through a shield amplifies its effect to a significant extent, effectively making it into a shield you can "turn on and off" for stronger magnetic fields than what it would normally be used for,

If so, could I run AC, or pulsed dc current through it to repeatedly block and release the field, simulating a significant oscillating(in this case , turning on and off again) magnetic field at normally unobtainable frequencies(sush as 30 ghz)

Comment: Can you explain why you think this *might* work? What theory are you invoking?

Comment: I had the hypothesis that the current would redirect the field where the two interacted with each other.

Comment: What physical theory led you to that hypothesis?

Comment: electrons, due to their spin are effectively tiny magnets and therefore electric current has magnetic properties, including tiny magnetic fields flowing in it, these flowing fields I wondered if they could perhaps push an encroaching magnetic field away from an area

Comment: High current generating high fields can saturate a magnetic material, reducing its effective permeability. Thus you may find ways to DECREASE shielding capability with high current. However switching the currents involved at 30GHz? ... difficult to impossible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would normally think of a magnetic shield as attenuating, that is multiplying by a number less than 1, an external field from one side (the agressor) to the other side (the victim).

Regardless of whether a conductor is magnetic or not, running a current through it generates a magnetic field round it. This magnetic field adds to any others that are present in the region around the shield.

Therefore the action of an externally applied current in a shield is not the same as turning the shield on and off, or even modulating its attenuation behaviour in any way.

30GHz will remain unobtainable to most people, especially if approached like this.